# How to access to the elements properties inside a Repeater?

Tags: asp.net, list, repeater, datasource

I have a *Repeater* control who has its dataSource setted with a typed object list and in the inline code I want to access to its elements properties inside the *ItemTemplate* tag. I tried this with the eval expression but it does not work:

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <tr>
    <td><%# Eval("code") %></td>
    <td><%# Eval("description") %></td>
  </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Any ideas?
Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use: `<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "field name") %>`

Answer (score 0):

Does your object have a property called "code". Remember it's case sensitive.

e.g. If your object were...

```
public class MyObj
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

And you were binding a `Collection<MyObj>` to your datasource,

Then you're repeater would look like...

```
<asp:repeater id="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <headertemplate>
      <table border="1">
        <tr>
          <td><b>Code</b></td>
          <td><b>Description</b></td>
        </tr>
    </headertemplate>

    <itemtemplate>
      <tr>
        <td> <%# Eval("Code") %> </td>
        <td> <%# Eval("Description") %> </td>
      </tr>
    </itemtemplate>

    <footertemplate>
      </table>
    </footertemplate>
  </asp:repeater>
```

Comment: Thanks Eoin but it's what I tried, it gave me an error about it can only be used in the context of a databound control.